# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ReactElement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

I am trying to display three components in the browser, but I am
   getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.
   The anonymous function is pointing to the react internal files. It
   would be great if you guys could let me know how to debug and fix the
   error. I'm providing the main js file which causes the error

**I debugged at this line `ReactCompositeComponent_mountComponent @ ReactPerf.js?94d4:66` It's throwing some object... but I'm not sure how to proceed.
`output: renderedComponent = Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: Object…}`**

**error**

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ReactElement.js?49af:112 

ReactElement.createElement @ ReactElement.js?49af:112
ReactElementValidator.createElement @ ReactElementValidator.js?0630:223
redux-ball_render @ redux-ball.jsx?ed37:53
(anonymous function) @ makeAssimilatePrototype.js?04ea:15
ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?3093:587
ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?3093:607
ReactCompositeComponent__renderValidatedComponent @ ReactPerf.js?94d4:66
ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?3093:220
ReactCompositeComponent_mountComponent @ ReactPerf.js?94d4:66
ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?bb76:37
```

**code**

```
import Basketball from 'sports-players';
import CarRacing from 'sports-players';
import Football from 'sports-players';

export default {

};
```

Comment: You probably have a recursive, infinite rendering or something like that going on that exhausts memory. Check your components and make sure you don't have some endless chain of render-triggering changes. I can't spot anything obvious in the code you posted.

Comment: @dannyjolie is there any way can we debug in debugger this error :(

Comment: In Chrome debugger, "Sources" tab, click the stop sign with pause symbol in it ("Break on exception"), and take a look at the stack trace when the error occurs. Or take a look at one of the countless other issues on StackOverflow related to "Maximum call stack size exceeded" ;)

Comment: If it helps, I encountered this same bug when I tried to make my component render itself, on accident (we'll call it a "typo"...). Maybe somewhere you have one component trying to render another component which in turn renders the first component. Good place to start looking, maybe...

Comment: @all bug was in the import staments...thanks guys